# Referencing join column in JPQL

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql, hibernate-mapping

With the query `Select c from Card c join User u on c.userId=u.userId where u.username=':u'`, I am trying to grab a list of Cards for the User based on the username available in User the table. However, I am running into the `antlr.SemanticException: could not resolve property: userId of: com.abc.SheridanSportsWAR.entity.Card` exception when I run it. How do I reference the `UserId` column in my `Card` entity?

Card.java

```
@Entity
public class Card {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="CardId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer cardId;
    
    @Column(name="CardNumber")
    private String cardNumber;
    
    @Column(name="CardType")
    private String cardType;
    
    @Column(name="ExpiryMonth")
    private String expiryMonth;
    
    @Column(name="ExpiryYear")
    private String expiryYear;
    
    @Column(name="CardHolder")
    private String cardHolder;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    private User userJ;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cardJ")
    private List<Purchase> purchases;
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="UserId")
    private Integer userId;
    
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="Username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="Password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="RoleName")
    private String roleName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userJ", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Card> cards;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. There is no field `userId` in your `Card` entity. Create one like that:

```
@Column(name = "UserId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer userId;
```

Comment: Your solution worked! Though, I do not understand why I have to specify the column itself when I have already mentioned the relationship on that column?

Comment: @Abhay it doesn't mean anything, in jpql you reference a **field**, not an annotation

Comment: Shouldn't userId be accessible through userJ as it is the field which is being annotated as the relationship between those entities? For example, userJ.userId. Unless of course, jpql is not designed to function that way.

Comment: @Abhay fields on both entities must appear in the relation, the way you describe it is joining `User` with itself

Comment: Oh btw I ran into **org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.abc.SheridanSportsWAR.entity.Card column: UserId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") ** but after modifying the annotation to @Column(name = "UserId", insertable=false, updatable=false) it worked. I have suggested the edit! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Abhay sorry, I'm banned for reviewing edits, but someone will probably do that. Thank you :)

Comment: That's weird; usually, using the `@ManyToOne` plus `@JoinColumn` annotations should be enough, and you wouldn't need to specificaly include a `userId` field on your entity, as long as the field exists on the table

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the problem seems to be that there's no `userId` column in the `card` table.

Comment: I do have the userId in card as it is the foreign key to the relationship b/w card and user. I just needed to exclusively map the column itself in my User entity class as @Andronicus mentioned in his answer.

Comment: That's weird; usually, using the `@ManyToOne` plus `@JoinColumn` annotations should be enough, and you wouldn't need to specificaly include a `userId` field on your entity, as long as the field exists on the table.

Comment: That is what I thought! But it could also be because I changed the Naming-Strategy in my application.properties file "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl"